# Where does Rey get the book she reads in The Rise of Skywalker to find the holocron?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker, rey

Assuming all the ancient Jedi texts were destroyed in *The Last Jedi*, are these Luke's personal notes? And did she return to get them or were they in Leia's possession?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Rey took them from Ahch-To in *The Last Jedi*, we see them aboard the Falcon at the end of the film.

This is confirmed in *The Rise of Skywalker: The Visual Dictionary*:

> It was Luke Skywalker's conviction that the library on Ahch-To should be destroyed, as the Jedi Order had been locked in a ruinous cycle of galactic upheaval since its very inception. Rey - perhaps driven by her innate scavenger instincts - left with the books before they could be burned, hiding them aboard the *Millennium Falcon* without he Master's knowledge.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the completeness of the films and was surprised by this seeming miss but its right there great response!!

Comment: In particular, the OP's assumption that they were destroyed is invalid.  They had been stolen before the random lightning bolt strike inconveniently destroyed the tree for no particular reason.  The scene where you see them is pretty quick.  It was fairly obvious to me seeing it in the theater, but on Netflix it was very hard to pick out the details necessary to understand that quick reveal (and also hard to even pause it during the reveal, if even possible).

Comment: I never considered the idea that Rey stole them. I had assumed that Luke stowed them on the Falcon when he boarded it that one time, but that didn't quite line up with him attempting to destroy them later on in the movie. It make sense that Rey stole them as she simply *has* them at the start of Rise of Skywalker.

Comment: The way it played out on screen implied, to me, that Rey stole the books, and Yoda burned down the tree to cover for her (yeah, I know, force ghosts interacting with the physical world...and why the need to cover for Rey...and.....yadda yadda. I'm just saying that's what everything _looked_ like). The fact that Rey had to books was part of the meaning behind "She has everything she needs"

Comment: Interesting POV on how they got there. I had assumed (post ROS) that they were duplicates that Leia had for her training, and that she had stashed them on the Falcon ages ago/gifted them to Rey when she was training her.

Comment: As Benjamin said, Yoda *told* Luke that Rey has the books, but Luke didn't understand him, just like he didn't understand "pass on what you have learned".

Comment: @DaveRGP the Visual Dictionary confirms Rey took them before Yoda “destroyed” them. I’ll edit if I remember when I get a hold of my copy again.